# Multi-root setup

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I got this message when editing my Go project in vscode:

```
The Go language server is currently not supported in a multi-root set-up with different GOPATHs.
```

My question is: what is a "multi-root-set-up"? I do **not** intend to make my project "multi-root". How to avoid this message, and let the language server analyze my code?

BTW, the directory layout of my project is:

```
drwxrwxr-x 5 xrfang xrfang 4096  1月 21 22:33 docs
drwxrwxr-x 2 xrfang xrfang 4096  1月 21 22:33 exp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xrfang xrfang  789  2月  3 20:52 Makefile
drwxrwxr-x 3 xrfang xrfang 4096  2月 12 22:03 pkg
drwxrwxr-x 7 xrfang xrfang 4096  1月 31 11:56 resources
drwxrwxr-x 8 xrfang xrfang 4096  2月 12 21:27 src
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xrfang xrfang  304  1月 21 22:33 TODO
-rwxrwxr-x 1 xrfang xrfang  395  1月 21 22:33 upgrade.sh
drwxrwxr-x 2 xrfang xrfang 4096  2月 12 21:28 utils
```

The `go.mod` file is in `src` directory.  And `pkg` is generated by the compiler, which is quite strange, because most of my other Go project does not generate pkg in the repository folder.

Comment: Didn't https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/issues/2431 help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using modules (go.mod), try to open vscode from the directory where go.mod exists.

If you are using GOPATH with the multiple paths and your intention is to work in the GOPATH mode, that's not supported as Ian said.

I hope https://github.com/golang/vscode-go#setting-up-your-workspace provides more info.

Also, make sure to have `"go.inferGopath"` setting disabled. I suspect the repository has been structured to work with the GOPATH mode and append the workspace root to the GOPATH. It's possible that vscode Go plugin + gopls does not like it. :-(

Comment: the project was created before go mod is introduced. I have refactored it to work with go mod, which is now the src sub directory.  All non-go assets resides outside of the src folder.

Comment: You can check the GOPATH the extension is using by running `Go: Current GOPATH` command. When the infer mode kicks in, it magically :-( prepends the `${workspaceRoot}/src/` directory in the GOPATH and it will try to install gopls and other tools in `${workspaceRoot}/bin/` directory. So, double check `"go.inferGopath"` setting and make sure to disable it. If you still have an issue, file an issue with the gopls trace. (there is a troubleshooting guide that discusses how to capture the trace).

Answer (score 0):

The error message is referring to your `GOPATH` environment variable.  `GOPATH` permits multiple paths separate by a colon, but gopls does not support that.

Comment: The GOPATH environment has only **ONE** path, which is `/home/xrfang/go`.   I don't know why it insist on install gopls etc into the project's bin folder. It is fixed by setting go.toolGopath in vscode. However, I don't know why that option exists at all.

Comment: do you mean that with go mod, I should **NOT** set GOPATH environment anyway, and go will save its assets globally, which the user do not need to bother?

Comment: In module mode, with a go.mod file, the GOPATH is used primarily to hold the module cache.  You don't have to set it GOPATH, in which case Go will use a default value.  Or you can set it to control where the module cache is put.